# Error calling stored procedure from trigger in Oracle Database 11g

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, stored-procedures, trigger, sqlplus, java

I'm trying to create a trigger that calls some Java code whenever a table is inserted/updated.  I'm aware of possible performance issues, I don't need advice that I should not do this; I just need to know what I'm doing wrong.

I've created the following Java source:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED TryJavaHelperSource AS
import java.io.*;
public class TryJavaHelper {
    public static void Run(String arg1, String arg2) throws Exception
    {
        // …
        return;
    }
}
/
```

And I created a stored procedure that calls this Java source:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TryJavaHelperRun (arg1 IN VARCHAR2, arg2 IN VARCHAR2)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'TryJavaHelper.Run (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)';
/
```

I'm trying to create a trigger on this table:

```
create table TryTable ( 
    arg1 varchar2(20), 
    arg2 varchar2(100) 
);
```

I get an compile error when I attempt to create the following trigger:

```
create or replace trigger TRYTABLE_BEF_UPD_ROW
before update or insert on TryTable
for each row
begin
    CALL TryJavaHelperRun(:new.arg1, :new.arg2);
end;
/
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
SQL> sho err
Errors for TRIGGER TRYTABLE_BEF_UPD_ROW:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/6      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TRYJAVAHELPERRUN" when
         expecting one of the following:
         := . ( @ % ;
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "TRYJAVAHELPERRUN" to
         continue.
```

Why is this error occurring, and how do I fix it?

UPDATE:

It looks like it works when I take out the `CALL` statement.  What are the rules governing when to use `CALL` and when to just type the name of the function/procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your trigger doesn't need the `CALL` keyword.

```
create or replace trigger TRYTABLE_BEF_UPD_ROW
before update or insert on TryTable
for each row
begin
    TryJavaHelperRun(:new.arg1, :new.arg2);
end;
/
```

Generally, you should never use `CALL` in a PL/SQL block-- just execute the procedure.  I assume that `CALL` is some ancient leftover syntactic remnant from some ancient version of Oracle.  It allows you to replace the entire PL/SQL block that is the trigger body with a single `CALL` statement, i.e.

```
create or replace trigger TRYTABLE_BEF_UPD_ROW
  before update or insert on TryTable
  for each row
  call TryJavaHelperRun(:new.arg1, :new.arg2)
/
```

Personally, I've never come across a case where there was any benefit to ditching the "normal" PL/SQL syntax in favor of using `CALL` in a trigger.

This assumes that you can call the `TryJavaHelperRun` procedure successfully in general.

Comment: I copied the "call" syntax from the book "Oracle Database 10g: The Complete Reference" in the section titled "Calling Procedures Within Triggers", where it does exactly this.  I assume this changed since 10g, as I am using 11g-r2.

Comment: @notfed - The `CALL` syntax hasn't changed in forever-- what works in 10.1 works in 11.2 just as well.  You don't have a `BEGIN` or an `END` when you are using the `CALL` syntax (see my second example).  In general, though, I'd strongly suggest avoiding the `CALL` syntax entirely.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the advice, I will certainly avoid it from here on. (I think it looks ugly anyway.)

Comment: BTW: In the book (p. 546) , it says "Rather than creating a large block of code within a trigger body, you can save the code as a stored procedure and call the procedure from within the trigger, by using the **call** command."

Comment: @notfed - Putting the actual logic in a stored procedure rather than having lots of code in trigger bodies is definitely a good idea.  Using the paleolithic `CALL` syntax rather than the standard PL/SQL block to actually execute the stored procedure is where I have a dispute.  `CALL` is valid, it's just extremely unusual and sufficiently different from every other PL/SQL block you'll ever encounter that I can't see any benefit to using it (well, it does save typing 4 characters, so I guess there is *some* benefit).

Comment: But saving 4 characters is a benefit of *not* using `CALL`.

Comment: @notfed - In the normal case, you have to type both 'BEGIN' and 'END' (8 characters).  In the `CALL` case, you just have to type `CALL` (4 characters) so you save 4 characters.  Not, of course, that avoiding typing 4 characters is a meaningful benefit.  But the `CALL` syntax is marginally shorter.